# Putting into a single loop response code and response time of a website

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, pycurl

I want to request 10 times a website and to see each time the status code, the start transfer time and the total time response time. I don't see how to look for these 3 informations into the same loop since I have only managed to request 10 times the status code and then 10 times the response time into two different loops meaning my data have no value because status codes have no relation with response time.

```
#First Loop
n = 10  

results = []
for r in range (0,n):
    resp = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        response_code = 200.0
    else:
        response_code = 0.00
    results.append(response_code)
 
#Second loop
total_time=np.zeros(n)
start_transfer_time =np.zeros(n)
n = 10
for i in range (0,n):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, "https://stackoverflow.com")
    ts = timeit.default_timer()
    c.perform()
    start_transfer_time[i] = c.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)
    total_time[i]= c.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

pycurl has HTTP_CODE

```py
import pycurl

n = 10 

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, "https://stackoverflow.com")

results = []
start = []
total = []
for r in range(n):
    curl.perform()
    results.append(curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE))
    start.append(curl.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME))
    total.append(curl.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME))


for s, t, r in zip(start, total, results):
    print(s, t, r)
```